# Executing Stored Procedure Oracle C#

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I'm trying to execute a procedure that I created on my oracle DB, but I'm having problems because it never finds the procedure, I already follow the documentation for oracle connection on here (http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/) but it didn't worked well. This is my code:

```
public static void ActualizarPacienteNn(Int64 idPacienteNN, Int64 idPaciente, string nombreUsuario, string contrasena)
{
    OracleConnection conexion = new OracleConnection();
    conexion = GenerarConexionOracle(nombreUsuario, contrasena);
    /*  
    OracleParameter[] parametros_procedimiento=new OracleParameter[]
    {
        new OracleParameter("ID_HCL_NN",idPacienteNN),
        new OracleParameter("ID_HCL_PACIENTE",idPaciente)
    };
    */

    OracleCommand comando = new OracleCommand();//se crea un comando
    comando.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    comando.CommandText = "PROCEDURE";
    comando.Connection = conexion;
    comando.ParameterCheck = true;

    try
    {
        conexion.Open();
        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(comando);
        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    catch (OracleException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        conexion.Close();

    }

    conexion.Close();
}
```

The error says, OBJECT "PROCEDURE" does not exist. (And I'm sure that the procedure exists).

I'm working with devart dotconnect, and an oracle DB 11g. Thank you.

Comment: and your Stored Procedure name is "PROCEDURE"?

Comment: Is the stored procedure owned by the same schema/user that you use in the connection string? If not, you would need to qualify the procedure name with the appropriate schema, e.g. "someschema.PROCEDURE". It could also be an issue of the account you are using in your connection string not having been granted rights to the stored procedure. If you log in through SQL Plus (or similar) with the same credentials as in your connection string, can you see and execute the stored procedure from there?

Comment: This is the line you are missing: `comando.CommandText = "nameOfTheStoredProcedure";`....

Comment: @Robert Rozas, OP has CommandText in code

Comment: Yes, but the string is wrong...unless his SP was called "Procedure"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like this, according to the docs

```
public static void ActualizarPacienteNn(Int64 idPacienteNN, Int64 idPaciente, string nombreUsuario, string contrasena)
{
  //Establish connection
  OracleConnection conexion = new OracleConnection();
  conexion = GenerarConexionOracle(nombreUsuario, contrasena);

  conexion.Open();
  //Set up comando to reference stored procedure 'usp_ActualizaPaciente'
  OracleCommand comando = new OracleCommand("usp_ActualizaPaciente", myConn);
  comando.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  comando.ParameterCheck = true;

  //Sample of how to bind parameters to the Stored Procedure
  OracleParameter myInParam1 = new OracleParameter();
  myInParam1.Value = idPaciente;
  myInParam1.ParameterName = "idPaciente";
  comando.Parameters.Add(myInParam1);
  myInParam1.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;

  //Execute the procedure.
  comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
  Console.WriteLine("Done");
  conexion.Close();
}
```

#### Docs: http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/articles/parameters.html